# Check whether checkbox is checked or not in page load itself by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

I have below checkbox and span tag in .Net MVC 3 page,

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckedStatus, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "cbCheckedStatus7" }, { "name", "cbCheckedStatus" }, { "class", "onchange" } })
<span id="spBlueCheckbox" style="display: none; color: blue;"> Some message</span>
```

Jquery:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#cbCheckedStatus7').on('change', function () {            
            $('#spBlueCheckbox').slideToggle(this.checked);
        });
```

if the checkbox is checked, i need to show the span tag, or else hide it. initially the spab tag is hidden.

I have written jquery to do the above scenario, but it is only working if i click manually by mouse. What i need is, when i navigate from previous page to this page, the checkbox is checked by default based DB flag, but the span tag is not shown.

Comment: Create a condition serverside that inserts the `display:none` style only if the checkbox isn't checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call below jquery on page load :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // do initial check and make show / hide
    if($('#cbCheckedStatus7').is(':checked')){ // check if checkbox checked
       $('#spBlueCheckbox').show();
    }

   // add change handler
   $('#cbCheckedStatus7').on('change', function () {            
       $('#spBlueCheckbox').slideToggle(this.checked);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
if($('#cbCheckedStatus7').is(':checked')){
   $('#spBlueCheckbox').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     ($('#cbCheckedStatus7').is(':checked')) ? $('#spBlueCheckbox').show(); : $('#spBlueCheckbox').hide();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit your code to this :**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#cbCheckedStatus7').on('change', function () { 
        if(this.checked)           
            $('#spBlueCheckbox').show();//or slide up or down
        else
            $('#spBlueCheckbox').hide();//or slide up or down
        });
```

**and ADD this to end of the page that contains the checkbox**

```
$('#cbCheckedStatus7').change();
```